# type '_Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
[{
    "getOtherCategoryCompaniesList_resp": [{
            "messageInfo": {
                "message_text": "Other Services List.",
                "alert_title": "Services List",
                "product_category_id": "56",
                "Success": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "companies": [{
                    "product_type_id": 1946,
                    "company_id": 609,
                    "product_name": "_All Puja",
                    "product_company_logo": "https://bhagva.in/imgs/icons/prod_category/logo.png"
                },
                {
                    "product_type_id": 1753,
                    "company_id": 535,
                    "product_name": "Aasa Maai Vrat Katha",
                    "product_company_logo": "https://bhagva.in/imgs/icons/prod_category/logo.png"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

This is my model class which i have generate online from json to pojo in  dart

```
class Poojlistmodel {
  int? producttypeid;
  int? companyid;
  String? productname;
  String? productcompanylogo;

  Poojlistmodel(
      {this.producttypeid,
      this.companyid,
      this.productname,
      this.productcompanylogo});

  Poojlistmodel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    producttypeid = json['product_type_id'];
    companyid = json['company_id'];
    productname = json['product_name'];
    productcompanylogo = json['product_company_logo'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['product_type_id'] = producttypeid;
    data['company_id'] = companyid;
    data['product_name'] = productname;
    data['product_company_logo'] = productcompanylogo;
    return data;
  }
}

class GetOtherCategoryCompaniesListResp {
  MessageInfo? messageInfo;
  List<Poojlistmodel?>? companies;

  GetOtherCategoryCompaniesListResp({this.messageInfo, this.companies});

  GetOtherCategoryCompaniesListResp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    messageInfo = json['messageInfo'] != null
        ? MessageInfo?.fromJson(json['messageInfo'])
        : null;
    if (json['companies'] != null) {
      companies = <Poojlistmodel>[];
      json['companies'].forEach((v) {
        companies!.add(Poojlistmodel.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['messageInfo'] = messageInfo!.toJson();
    data['companies'] =
        companies != null ? companies!.map((v) => v?.toJson()).toList() : null;
    return data;
  }
}

class MessageInfo {
  String? messagetext;
  String? alerttitle;
  String? productcategoryid;
  String? success;

  MessageInfo(
      {this.messagetext,
      this.alerttitle,
      this.productcategoryid,
      this.success});

  MessageInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    messagetext = json['message_text'];
    alerttitle = json['alert_title'];
    productcategoryid = json['product_category_id'];
    success = json['Success'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['message_text'] = messagetext;
    data['alert_title'] = alerttitle;
    data['product_category_id'] = productcategoryid;
    data['Success'] = success;
    return data;
  }
}

class Root {
  List<GetOtherCategoryCompaniesListResp?>? getOtherCategoryCompaniesListresp;

  Root({this.getOtherCategoryCompaniesListresp});

  Root.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['getOtherCategoryCompaniesList_resp'] != null) {
      getOtherCategoryCompaniesListresp = <GetOtherCategoryCompaniesListResp>[];
      json['getOtherCategoryCompaniesList_resp'].forEach((v) {
        getOtherCategoryCompaniesListresp!
            .add(GetOtherCategoryCompaniesListResp.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['getOtherCategoryCompaniesList_resp'] =
        getOtherCategoryCompaniesListresp != null
            ? getOtherCategoryCompaniesListresp!
                .map((v) => v?.toJson())
                .toList()
            : null;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This code i am using to network hit

```
class MySpecilistRepo {
  final BaseApiServices _apiServices = NetworkApiService();

  Future<dynamic> dashboardApi(String userId,String productCategoryId) async {
    try {
      var params = {
        "getOtherCategoryCompaniesList_req": [
          {
            "requestInfo": {
              "user_id": userId,
              "product_category_id": productCategoryId
            }
          }
        ]
      };

      dynamic response =
          await _apiServices.authApiResponse(AppUrl.GET_LIST_OF_POOJA, params);
      print("dashboard $response");
      return Poojlistmodel.fromJson(response);
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

When i run code i am getting exception that type '_Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>' is not a subtype of type 'String' i don't know where i am doing mistake while i have generate model class using online please help me where i am doing wrong i trying first time network hit in flutter .

Thanks

Comment: If you run your Flutter app in Debug mode, you should be able to see exactly which line is causing this error. Could you do that and share the info with us?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
return Poojlistmodel.fromJson(response);
```

to

```
  final root = Root.fromJson(jsonDecode(response)[0]);
  final List<Poojlistmodel?> models = root.getOtherCategoryCompaniesListresp![1]!.companies!;
  print(models.map((e) => e?.productname)); // this will print _All Puja, Aasa Maai Vrat Katha
  return models;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but still i am getting same error //pastecode.io/s/5f9mcj4v

Answer (score 0):

This is little nested data, but it will easy to understand the process. First get the data, then get the companies. You can [play with simple json](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/jsonFormating/sample1.dart) .

```dart
  Future<dynamic> dashboardApi(String userId, String productCategoryId) async {
    try {
      dynamic response =
          await _apiServices.authApiResponse(AppUrl.GET_LIST_OF_POOJA, params);
      // dynamic response = fixture('data.json');
      
      final data = jsonDecode(response) as List? ?? [];
      final companies = data.map((e) => Poojlistmodel.fromJson(e)).toList();//it would be nice to call it fromMap instead
      print(companies.length); 
      // this returns list of model. 
      // you can get the first like companies.first, 
      // also the check list is empty or not.
      
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Md. Yeasin Sheikh but i am getting same Error  //pastecode.io/s/fv86gcjf

Comment: Can you try `jsonDecode(response.body)`

Comment: this is my netowrk code i forgot add in question https://pastecode.io/s/rwx8384g

Comment: Can you check `response.runtimeType` & while you are already handling it another class. try `final data = response as List? ?? [];`

Comment: I have debug code i have seen request is going     {\"getOtherCategoryCompaniesList_req\":[{\"requestInfo\":{\"user_id\":\"3\",\"product_category_id\":\"56\"}}]} which is wrong that is creating problem